# Triggering events when location of android device is changed

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude

I am trying to develop a android application in which I need to trigger events and push notifications to the device whenever I come to a specific area with the help of the GPS coordinates..

I searched many forums but I am still in mess ..not able to figure out .. Can anyone suggest me some websites where I could refer??

Comment: Look up fused location provider. There are tons of examples out there, a lot of them are as close to cut and paste as you can get.

Answer (score 4):

What you mean is called **Geofencing** and here is a description on how to do it with Android:

http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: I deduced the whole geofencing API without knowing it's actual name. Then I came across this. My only advantage is that what I wrote falls back to coarse location when the user is not near any of the fences.